# Hide Custom Action

Tags: permissions

Hide Custom Action from all users and Groups except for anonymous users.

For example I create custom action for registration page and I want this to appear for anonymous users only , how can this be done?

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  </HideCustomAction>
  <CustomAction  Id="Id1" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"   GroupId="SiteActions" Title="SignUp">
    <UrlAction Url="http://dina/_layouts/15/ListsAndPages/RegisterPage.aspx"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Comment: SPSecurityTrimmedControl may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I haven't tested it, you can try setting `Rights = EmptyMask` in `CustomAction`

> EmptyMask Has no permissions on the Web site. Not available through
>   the user interface.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
Moreover, RegisterPage.aspx page in your case needs to inherit from `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase`. You also need to override `AllowAnonymousAccess`. Example:

```
public partial class RegisterPage : UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
{   
    protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot Nadeem , but when I sign in I still can see the  Registration page